# jQuery Datepicker opens twice after click on next month (using 2 Datepickers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, button, datepicker

I have a site where I use two datepickers. The first one selects the departure and the second one the arrival.

The second datepicker is opened by the "onClose:" function of the first.

Until this point there is no problem. It occurres, when I click on `next month` in the second datepicker. It seems, that the datepicker closes for half an second and reopens in the same month as before. After that I can normally use the `next month` button.

I don't get the problem. I made a fiddle with the minimal requirements to reproduce the problem, to be sure, there is no other code in my project that produces the problem.

Fun fact: It works fine in IE 10 and not in FF/Chrome.

Here comes the fiddle:     http://jsfiddle.net/xe247evv/1/

```
<input type="text" value="1.1.1700" class="datepicker" id="datepickerFromDate2" readonly="readonly">
<input type="text" value="5.1.1700" class="datepicker" id="datepickerToDate2" readonly="readonly">

jQuery("#datepickerFromDate2").datepicker({
  onClose: function() {
      jQuery('#datepickerToDate2').datepicker('show');
  }
});
jQuery("#datepickerToDate2").datepicker();
```

To reproduce it:

1. Click left datepicker and select date.
2. Click on the right arrow for next month in the new opened datepicker.
3. you'll see a bug.

Could someone help me with this strange behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, thanks for your help Dave Salomon. But i have another solution inspired by an answer from TrueBlueAussie who maybe deleted his answer because of a js-error in his fiddle.

He mentioned the problem, that both datepicker use the same "ui-datepicker-div" and that this could cause a problem.

My solution was to make a little window.setTimeout before the opening of the second datepicker.

See the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xe247evv/6/

```
jQuery("#datepickerFromDate2").datepicker({
  onClose: function() {
      window.setTimeout(function(){
          jQuery('#datepickerToDate2').datepicker('show');
      }, 0);
  }
});
jQuery("#datepickerToDate2").datepicker();
```

Comment: Sure, no problem, this works too. You could make your setTimeout delay to 0, and it'll still work correctly.

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a jQuery UI bug.

One workaround is to set the datepicker to show by clicking a button, rather than on field focus, and then hiding that button.

```
jQuery("#datepickerToDate2").datepicker({showOn:"button"}).next('.ui-datepicker-trigger').hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/xe247evv/5/